# Why are Fréchet spaces not automatically second-countable?

Tags: general-topology

It is well-known that a countable product of second-countable spaces is second-countable. However, as far as I know there are non-separable Fréchet spaces, at least I have seen explicit references to "separable Fréchet spaces", so it doesn't seem like every Fréchet space is separable. Now both the product topology and the topology on a Fréchet space induced by the family of semi-norms are initial topologies. And it seems to me that the proof that a countable product of second-countable spaces is second-countable doesn't use anything except the fact that the product topology is initial.

Here is a proof(?) that any initial topology induced by countably many maps into second-countable spaces is second-countable:

We start with the general setup, without assuming countability of any kind: Let $((X_\alpha, \mathcal T_\alpha))_{\alpha \in A}$ be a family of spaces, and let $X$ be a set. Now let maps $f_\alpha \colon X \to X_\alpha$ induce a topology $\mathcal T$ on $X$. That is, sets on the form $f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ for $U_\alpha \in \mathcal T_\alpha$ form a subbasis for $\mathcal T$. In other words, open sets in $X$ are (arbitrary) unions of finite intersections of sets $f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$.

Now let $\mathcal B_\alpha = \{ B_\alpha^\lambda \mid \lambda \in \mathbb \Lambda_\alpha \}$ be any basis for $\mathcal T_\alpha$. I claim that sets on the form $f_\alpha^{-1}(B_\alpha^\lambda)$ constitute a subbasis for $\mathcal T$. Let $\mathcal T'$ be the topology generated by the sets $f_\alpha^{-1}(B_\alpha^\lambda)$. Clearly we have $\mathcal T' \subseteq \mathcal T$, so to prove this claim it is enough to show that every element of a subbasis for $\mathcal T$ lies in $\mathcal T'$, since $\mathcal T$ is the coarsest topology on $X$ that contains these sets.

Take such a subbasis element $f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ (with notation as above). Since $U_\alpha \in \mathcal T_\alpha$ and $\mathcal B_\alpha$ is a basis for $\mathcal T_\alpha$, we can write $U_\alpha = \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda_\alpha'} B_\alpha^\lambda$ for some $\Lambda_\alpha' \subseteq \Lambda_\alpha$. But then

$$ f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)
= f_\alpha^{-1} \biggl( \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda_\alpha'} B_\alpha^\lambda \biggr)
= \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda_\alpha'} f_\alpha^{-1}(B_\alpha^\lambda), $$

which clearly lies in $\mathcal T'$. Hence $\mathcal T \subseteq \mathcal T'$, so the two topologies are equal.

Now assume that all index sets $A$ and $\Lambda_\alpha$ are countable. Then there are countably many sets $B_\alpha^\lambda$, so countably many $f_\alpha^{-1}(B_\alpha^\lambda)$. Taking finite intersections of these sets also yields a countable collection of sets, but this is a basis for $\mathcal T$, so $X$ is second-countable.

---

Finally, if the $f_\alpha$ are semi-norms and we let them induce a topology on $X$, then this topology is *a priori* induced by maps $x \mapsto f_\alpha(x - y)$ for $y \in X$ and $\alpha \in A$ (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697735/definition-of-topology-induced-by-seminorms)), of which there in general are uncountably many. But such a map is continuous iff $f_\alpha$ itself is continuous, so we may assume that there are only countably many such maps (given that $A$ is countable). Hence every Fréchet space is second-countable.

---

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on here? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Aren't there already non-separable Hilbert spaces?

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes, I guess that's true, didn't think of that. So there are obviously non-separable Fréchet spaces. But then where does my argument fail?

Comment: I'll look at it a bit later ...

Comment: Why is the topology induced by a family of semi-norms the initial topology? Even in the case of a single norm $\|\cdot\|:V\to\Bbb R$ the induced topology is always Hausdorff (metrizable even), while the initial topology is not even $T_0$ since if $x\neq x'$ are such that $\|x\|=\|x'\|$ they cannot be separated in the initial topology

Comment: In your particular example of the absolute value on $\Bbb R$ the initial topology disagrees with the Euclidean topology, but the topology induced by the absolute value as a norm *is* the Euclidean topology since all norms on a finite dimensional real vector space induce the same topology

Comment: Regarding continuity of addition that always holds for Frechét spaces, either they are topological vector spaces as part of the definition, or it follows from the seminorms definition by using the correct notion of topology induced by a family of seminorms (namely the one you mention at the end, induced by the maps $x\to f_\alpha(x-y)$, though I don't understand the step where you claim you can only consider countably many such maps)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti The claim (which is wrong) that it is sufficient to consider countably many maps $x \mapsto f_\alpha(x - y)$ was supposed to follow by continuity of addition, since if addition were continuous then continuity of $f_\alpha$ (for countably many $\alpha$) would imply continuity of the above maps. But addition is not continuous in the initial topology induced by the $f_\alpha$ (the "incorrect" induced topology), so the claim was wrong. Your point that such a topology is not $T_0$ is a nice way to see it, thank you for that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have found the flaw in my argument. I claimed that if the map $f_\alpha$ were continuous, then $x \mapsto p_\alpha(x-y)$ would also be continuous. But this relies on addition being continuous, and I don't believe this is the case.

Let $p \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the norm $p(x) = \lvert x \rvert$, and let $\tilde{\mathbb{R}}$ be the real line equipped with the *initial* topology induced by $p$ (i.e. *not* the norm topology, at least *a priori*). Notice that open sets in $\tilde{\mathbb{R}}$ are symmetric around $0$ (so this clearly isn't the norm topology -- case closed).

But to give an explicit counterexample to addition being continuous: Let $A \colon \tilde{\mathbb{R}} \to \tilde{\mathbb{R}}$ be the map $x \mapsto x + 1$. I claim that this map is *not* continuous, say at $x = -1$. For $\epsilon > 0$ the interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon) = p^{-1}([0,\epsilon))$ is a neighbourhood of $A(-1) = 0$. For $A$ to be continuous at $-1$ there must be a neighbourhood $U$ of $-1$ such that $A(U) \subseteq (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Then $U$ must contain the point $-1$, but then $1 \in U$, and $A(1) = 2 \not\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon$ small enough.

In case someone else has something clever to add (or something to correct me on) I will wait a bit before accepting this answer.